# Android: is screen "flickering" harmful?

Tags: android

I'm creating a "sophisticated phone disco" app where I'll implement screen changing colors pretty quickly, also adjusting brightness according.

Could this be harmful to the screen?

Comment: It could be harmful to those who have epilepsy.

Comment: I recommend using _pretty colours, quickly._